# how to end one conversation in python telegram bot when another one is trigger

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I have two conversation handlers that have a state with messageHandler of a number:

1. delete client debt conversation - the user gets a numbered list of his clients and is asked to type the number of the client he wants to delete debt to. this conversation is triggered by a callbackqueryhandler for "delete client" button.
2. send waze to link conversation -  the user gets a numbered list of his clients and is asked to type the number of the client he wants to get link to waze to his address. this conversation is triggered by a callbackqueryhandler for "send eaze link" button.

the problem is that when the user press on "delete debt" button and gets the list of his clients but then press the send link button and gets again the number of client, the bot doesnt send a waze to link but keep the delete debt conversation.
I want that when the waze link conversation is triggered the delete debt conversation will automatically end and when the user type number the message handler in the waze conversation handler will be execute

I tried to set per_char, per_message parametes to True, allow_reentry=True, add entry point of conv 1 to the fallbacks of conv 2 and opposite